# JsonConvert: How to ignore Integer types where the value is a specific number

Tags: c#, json

Is there a way to tell JsonConvert to ignore integer type values when they have a specific value?  I want to use the minValue of an Integer Type instead of 0 as the default type because 0 is a valid value.

Comment: Can you explain in brief

Comment: I'm guessing you are receiving `0` which is a valid number, however you want to return null on `-2,147,483,648` or something

Comment: When using  JsonConvert.SerializeObject, I have the option to use NullValueHandling and MissingMemberHandling which generates Json ignoring fields with Null values, but I also need to be able to ignore Integer types which I want to store with a minValue.

Comment: Yes, missing fields in the Json will be stored as a minValue (ex. -2.147,483,648) and when converted back to Json need to be ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Json.NET will respect `System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue` attribute, so you can do what you want like this:

```
class TestClass {
    [DefaultValue(int.MinValue)]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

var ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new TestClass() { Value = int.MinValue}, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
});
// serializes to empty object {}
Console.WriteLine(ser);

var ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new TestClass() { Value = 0}, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
});
// serializes to {"Value" : 0}
Console.WriteLine(ser);
```

If you don't want to decorate anything, you can use custom contract resolver:

```
class IntMinValueContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver {
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization) {
        var prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(int)) {
            // for int properties, set default value and ignore it when serializing
            // while populating while deserializing
            prop.DefaultValue = int.MinValue;
            prop.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate;
        }
        return prop;
    }
}

JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new IntMinValueContractResolver()
};
// serializes to empty object {}
var ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new TestClass() { Value = int.MinValue});
```

Comment: This works great, thanks.    I like to add that on JsonConvert.DeserializeObject the DefaultValueHandling has to be set to DefaultValueHandling.Populate for the default value to be picked up correctly.

Comment: For the second solution, is there a similar way to create a default value when using DeserializeObject as otherwise it is still necessary to use default attributes?

Comment: @JohnCambell What do you mean by "create default value"? If property  is omitted in json - populate it with `int.MinValue` when deserializing?

Comment: @JohnCambell if yes - just change the above code to `prop.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate;`

Comment: That's what I missed. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of creating a new object each time and passing that in the lambda to `DefaultSettings` on each access, is it worth it and OK to use a static instance then return that?

Comment: Note that the contract resolver approach works only if your property is "typed" as `int`. If the declared type is `object`, then this wont work.